bindiff verses bin-diffing tags
The bindiff tag has the following description:

Commercial binary diffing tool sold by Google (formerly zynamics/Sabre)

and until recently 9 questions. Out of those, only 4 (this, this, this and this) discuss the actual BinDiff tool, while the other 5 (this, this, this, this and this) ask questions related to binary differencing in general. 7 out of the 9 are questions by the same user, user3119546, and those are all of his questions. He also have 2 answers, one of which is about BinDiff.
I will now remove and retag the bindiff and bin-diffing tags to be faithfully representing the current tag intentions, but I think we should discuss this tag.

The current name is quite confusing, and I would suggest replacing it with something a bit more clear, such as tool-bindiff instead.
Although there's no such convention (and this might justify another discussion), in the particular case of BinDiff the name is actually the same as the action, and perhaps written in a more intuitive manner (compared to bin-diffing). IMHO the current tag names make it unclear to users that haven't seen these tags before.
Edit:
I've replaced bindiff with tool-bindiff, and copied the updated description from the old tag to the new tag.
I would now like to remove bindiff altogether and make it a synonym of bin-diffing but it appears I'm unable to do that.

Well, why not having a [tag:binary-diff] and keep the [tag:bindiff] as it is (it is the name of the tool after all, if we start changing [tag:idapro] into [tag:tool-idapro] and so on... it would be endless and would remove all interest in the [tag:tool] tag.

as I mentioned bindiff (compared to ida) is really similar to the general task so I think tool-bindiff is better than simply bindiff (only for that specific case), but can go either way. +1 on adding "binary-diff". I've taken any steps only because the only response was this one upvote, everyone's welcome to revert what I did in favor of anything the community prefers.

It is just that I am not so convinced that it does really make a huge difference... And, changing the existing solution can be misleading. So, I would vote for a status quo. Moreover, the fact that you got one  vote on your post does not really mean that this is a consensus... But, I might also just being too old and start to hate that things evolve... :-) Anyway, this is not really a crucial matter here. If you did the change, let it be as it is now. But, remember next time that only one vote is not really a consensus. ;-)

@Nirlzr: But, do not misinterpret me! I do not blame you! It is good to have people ready to do the job from time to time! :-) (I fear to have been a bit harsh with you without noticing it, sorry for that!).

All good. Don't worry :)
